# WCF Data Services (oData): Dependency Injection with DataService

Tags: c#, ioc-container, wcf-data-services, odata

How can I use my IoC container in a `DataService` and the `CurrentDataSource` inside for WCF Data Services? I have several services I want to pass into it. The "host" application or project for the `DataService` is based on ASP.NET MVC 2.0. My IoC container is setup in the `MvcApplication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as "clean" as integrating your IoC container deep into the WCF factory classes but if you want to supply a DataSource you could use the *Common Service Locator* (link at bottom) with your existing IoC container and override the *CreateDataSource* method of DataService

```
protected override MyEntityContext CreateDataSource() 
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyEntityContext>();
}
```

Common Service Locator library

http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/